# Can you add to a VSCode language's auto complete?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

We got a Ruby API for our application and I'm trying to figure out if I can make an extension for VSCode that add auto-complete for our API to the Intellisense feature of the editor.

With RubyMine I've done this by simply using stubs packaged as a gem. Adding the gem to the RubyMine project is all that I needed to have the editor provide code insight that included our API.

How can this be done for VSCode? I was hoping to build upon the existing vscode-ruby extension for Code. But I'm only finding examples of adding language extensions.

Comment: Have you looked at adding Snippets at all? I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for but worth a look https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets OR https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to questions like this I keep up to day with new technologies and tools.

I did a quick read of the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs), although VSCode support several language the page refers to [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode/Languages) for extensions, and [ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) is one of them.

Now, ruby extension claims to have IntelliSense and autocomplete, however if this does not detects your API, then you may need to create your own [language extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support). I assume that if your Ruby is an API, as you said, then VSCode has not access to the interface in order to provide the possible predictions.
Perhaps if you somehow could get the source code of the API VSCode would detect the interfaces, and life would be much easier.

Anyway, have a look to the [extensionAPI7Language-support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support)
There explain how to create

- Source code snippets
- Show Code completion Proposals

both of then have to be manually configured.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to extend an existing language server? It seems to be as rather overkill to reimplement intellisense and auto-complete for Ruby only to be able to provide code complete for our API.
The way RubyMine seems to work is that it parses the Gemfile and include autocomplete for the gems listed. This made it very easy to feed it our API as stubs via a gem. Had hoped VSCode had a similar light weight way to do the same thing.

Comment: I downloaded the source from rubyide/vscode-ruby and they do use CompletionItme in their code, I guess before implementing any changes in that you should ask directly to them, perhaps there is a better way. 
Let's see if any other drops a comment.